# Bias-variance trade-off in linear regression

Tags: regression, overfitting, mse, bias-variance-tradeoff

As it’s understood, in the bias-variance trade-off, variance refers to overfitting of the model and it examines the variability of output predictions.

Suppose we have a simple dataset with one predictor which relates perfectly linear with the target. For example, y = 3x. In that case, obviously the function that fits better is f(x) = 3x.

Defining the loss function as the squared error loss, we must have

Err(x) = E[(Y-f(x))^2]

which implies a zero error.

But, on the other hand, after decomposition, we have

Err(x) = bias^2 + variance + irreducible error.

Although the selected function fits perfectly the data, the variance of predictions is not null, so the error isn’t neither following this formula.

And, even more, if the relationship between the input and the target is perfectly linear (and later we check it’s also in test data), there’s no overfitting and, otherwise, variance is not null.

What’s wrong in this reasoning?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: As Raymond says,  I was confused because of the article “Understanding the bias-variance trade-off” in Towards Data Science. They decompose the MSE into variance and bias, through the next expression:

[image]

But, according what Raymond says, that wouldn’t be right. In fact, it’s not about the variance of output model itself (as it’s understood according the second term of the sum), but the variance among different predictions got in several samples of the original dataset.

Comment: Variance is not meant in terms of variance of multiple predictions.

Comment: The description is too vague to analyze.  What is your underlying probability model?  How do you intend us to understand "variance of predictions"?  What exactly is, or could be, changing?  You have placed us in a situation with one given, fixed dataset--and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

The key is, your first $Err(x)$

> Err(x) = E[(Y-f(x))^2]

refers to the error given one dataset and a model $f$ which was trained on such dataset.

However, your second $Err(x)$

> Err(x) = bias^2 + variance + irreducible error.

refers to the expected error over different datasets ($D$). You can see this by reading [this wiki section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff#Bias%E2%80%93variance_decomposition_of_mean_squared_error).

So they are two different concepts and not necessarily equal to one another.

In particular, as quoted from the same wiki section,

> $Var_D[\hat{f}(x; D)] = \mathbb E_D [(\mathbb E_D[\hat{f}(x;D)] - \hat{f}(x; D))^2]$

This variance talks about the variation of $\hat{f}(x; D)$ among different $D$, instead of the variance of your predictions by a model trained with a certain dataset.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was wrong. 

For further information, i think this lecture can be very useful: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4780/2018fa/lectures/lecturenote12.html

Comment: indeed. it is a very good resource!